# Update and Read the same variable using python Ray

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ray

I'm just studying about multiprocessing in Python. I have a code that updates the value of a variable in a process, and other processes read the value of this variable. This is working as I expected.

Now I just want to know if there is some way to do the same using the Ray library to improve the speed of execution if I need to run lots of processes reading it

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def write_to_dict(d, value):
    while True:
        value = value + 1
        d['key'] = value

def read_from_dict(d):
    while True:
        read = d['key']
        print(read)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    shared_dict = manager.dict()

    p1 = Process(target=write_to_dict, args=(shared_dict, 0))
    p2 = Process(target=read_from_dict, args=(shared_dict,))
    
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

---